# Predator technology stagnation

Tags: predator

If the Predator (or Yautja) civilization has indeed millions of years of existence as shown both in films (like the triceratops skull trophy) and expanded universe, why is their tech so stagnated? They’re barely above us in technology having things like slightly more sophisticated weapons, space ships and an Ironman-like mechanic suit. Things you’ll expect from a few more hundreds of years old civilization, not millions. A millions-year old civilization should be already around type 3 or 4 in the Kardashev scale.

If I think in a civilization with technology millions of years older than ours that would be something on the level of the Vorlon of Babylon 5, the Time Lords of Doctor Who or the Q of Star Trek, basically incomprehensible and magical as per Clarke’s law.

Comment: Some modern day hunters use bows. There’s no reason to believe that the technology we see used in the predator movies is their most advanced technology.

Comment: Could be, good point

Comment: Kardashev scale is probably vaporware everywhere in the universe. It's interesting for fiction, not so much for thermodynamics.

Comment: It is cowardly to hunt a deer with an ICBM.

Comment: I'd suggest the Predator venerates the hunt and the fact that his prey fights back. He wants to win, but not too easily.

Comment: With advance technology everything is magic. Perhaps it's so advance we do not understand how advance it is. Because of great UX design, 
This simple Armor suit and lense may look just a bit more advance. It's magic so advance even hairless monkey can use it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Though bow technology has definitely advanced a great deal since Agincourt (the battle that cemented the superiority of the English longbow in history).  A modern hunting bow might make use of carbon fiber, compound pull with multiple pully wheels, precision sighting, etc.  Henry V's army would be as impressed by modern bows as they would by firearms.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Predator shoots some kind of explosive plasma bolts from a shoulder cannon that tracks eye movement. Maybe there’s incremental improvement over the original plasma bolt weapons from 10,000 years ago that didn’t explode and required a weapon four times larger and ten times heavier and a crew of three.

Answer (score 59):

### Maybe there's a ceiling to technology.

The Kardashev scale is *completely* theoretical and therefore can lead to flawed assumptions, like that there is much further for us to go with technology when some things might simply be impossible under the laws of physics.  As an example, everyone was sure in the 1950s that we'd have flying cars by 1990. Flash forward to today an everyone is sure that we'll have artificial sapient intelligence in our lifetimes when we very well may (I would argue probably) never achieve it because it's impossible. Scientists now believe that faster-than-light travel is impossible, and they may be right. The Predators are pretty well advanced, but maybe they've hit the ceiling.

Remember, the Vorlon, the Time Lords, and Q are all just fantasy (despite the Star Trek fan tendency to claim the mantle of "real science fiction"). These are just speculative creations from peoples' imagination, not scientific benchmarks that civilizations should reach in a given amount of time.

### You may be overestimating their age and mis-identifying the skull.

What if evolution of life occurs in much the same way on very similar planets? There may be other very Earth-like worlds that are currently in their dinosaur phase with triceratops (or things that look very much like them) stomping around as you read this. In this case, *yautja* could hunt us one week and the dinosaurs next week. There are billions of planets out there, after all.

Further, the fact that the current day *yautja* had such a skull in their ship strongly suggests that it was a more recent kill. *Yautja* don't seem like an especially long lived species; if nothing else, their way of life is quite risky. Does it make sense that they'd be carrying around trophies that were millions of years old? Wouldn't the skull have broken down by now? It seems much more likely they killed that thing recently on a different planet.

### Culture drives technology development and technology use.

I have a friend who goes out into the woods every winter and hunts deer with a bow and arrow. This is in 2022 America--he "should" have a shotgun or a rifle, right? Well, he finds that using a bow is more challenging and hence more fun. The *yautja* might scale their technology to their prey so that they incur a risk and don't win too easily.

The fact that the culture seems so single-minded in their pursuits could also cause their technological development to stagnate or over-focus on hunting technology. Granted, our view of the *yautja* culture as a culture of hunters could be sampling bias, since nobody's made a movie about *yautja* doing anything else. Perhaps deer think humans have a hunting culture too?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138383/discussion-on-answer-by-ruffdove-predator-technology-stagnation).

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the great @ruffdove answer:

### We might see only a fragment of their culture

There is a great story by Stansław Lem, in which the main character describes that the whole culture of a certain planet is focused on killing giant beasts. Using explosives. From inside... <sup>1</sup>

In a different story, the same main character finds out (via a diplomatic note) that what he described before was just a... tourist attraction. <sup>2</sup>

The same might be true for Predators. We might see only a small group focused on some sort of Rite of Passage. We don't know, but there might be whole ships or planets, with more advanced technology NOT focused on the hunt.

<sup>1 *The Star diaries* - *The Fourteenth voyage*. The wannabe hunter covers himself with a tasty paste (with spices, and possibly mushroom sauce, but - God forbid - no pepper!) and waits for Squamp (a skyscraper-size creatures)to swallow him whole, then the hunter sets up the time bomb and waits for the second, laxative effect of the paste</sup>

<sup>2 *Observation on the Spot*</sup>

Comment: Like the parable of the blind men examining the elephant and each feeling a different part of the animal. If all you feel is the trunk, then you think an elephant is like a snake.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense because we never even see anything being built. We simply do not know anything. This can well be a rite of passage or a pastime tradition. While they likely do maintain their equipment - we never see (simply because it is not part of the story) some heavier repairs. Those may be the Samurai of their civilization. Someone has to build those ships and stuff and I have problems seeing the Predators we see in the movies coming up with the building plans.

Comment: What is this Lem story, incidentally?

Comment: @jogloran The first part was in "The fourteenth voyage" published in "The Star Diaries", the correction is a full-blown book called "Observation on the spot"

Answer (score 4):

I remember a short movie (*Relativity Theory*, S04E07 from the 1995 Outer Limits ([IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667937/), [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/TheOuterLimits1995S4E6RelativityTheory))):

> A survey team searching for resources for Earth lands on a promising planet which appears to be uninhabited. However, they soon come under attack and must decide how to respond.

It was revealed that it was some kind of summer camp for young aliens. Their parents were seriously pissed off after the killing and blew up the planet.

So the Predator may just be doing "survival games" or "hunting a rabbit with just a toothpick, in swimming trunks"

Comment: That was indeed an episode of the Outer Limits reboot, "Relativity Theory"

Comment: @RichieFrame: thank you! I updated the post with the information

Comment: Along with what @ericrussell in their answer about potentially having the capability to wipe out a city, but not being motivated to, I think this might actually be a relative answer; even in today's militaries, your average soldier isn't going to have access to the entire military arsenal.

Answer (score 2):

### Their tech is probably not stagnated, rather they stick to the same tech and tools, so as to honor the traditions of The Hunt

Considering how in our own culture hunting is currently viewed more so of as a sport, leisure and an adrenaline boost, as opposed to a survival detriment, I think we can safely state the same for the Yautja.

We can see the same with younger hunters entering the hobby in the 21st century, showing up with AR-15s on a boar hunt rather than a bolt action rifle, or an automatic shotgun as opposed to a double barrel on a bird hunt. In modern society technology has greatly impacted the thrill of the hunt, now it is not you and your marksmanship skills against the animal, but rather you and your wallet - how much are you willing to spend for a scope, bullets, rifle, etc. The prey is left with little to no chance to escape and pose a challenge.

As a result such practices are greatly frowned upon by old-school hunters in our society and they are quite vocal of their disapproval of the youth. We view them as boomers and simply move on.

In Yautja culture however, The Hunt is a rite of passage, honor is a prime cultural value and the elders are greatly respected. Perhaps the tech we see the Predator sporting are the bare minimums of the Yautja culture, the cemented tools of the trade, with any deviations and modernization being frowned upon as a weakness.

Just my opinion :))

Answer (score 2):

In the first Predator movie, there were occasions where the alien used a shoulder mounted laser, and then there was the last scene where it activated some type of nuclear bomb. That's still 20th or 21st century technology, but it seems they prefer to hunt using primitive weapons. I'm sure they could destroy an entire city from orbit, if they wanted. But they don't seem motivated by hate or revenge - just sport.